# Elasticsearch getting data repeatedly

Tags: elasticsearch

I search data from MYSQL with elasticsearch but when I restart the elasticsearch, Then search result comes duplicate. What should I do? Can anybody help?

Comment: i got a similar problem
did you solve it ?
i create a post too :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174920/elasticsearch-data-increase-duplicate-at-each-restart